# What are the testing types that can be supported by Selenium?

Tags: selenium

What are the testing types that can be supported by Selenium? Can Selenium be used for UI testing? Textual testing?

Comment: I'm confused - are you just looking for a brochure on Selenium? I think this is a bit too broad for our site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Selenium supports the following types of testing:

Functional Testing
Regression Testing

Comment: I would also add in End to End testing & Smoke Testing

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is a system for operating a web browser by remote control.  You can cause the browser to perform actions, and you can retrieve information in the DOM using different criteria.

Selenium is not a system for installing software, managing tests, or managing test data.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a good tool for UI testing wherein you need to automate the GUI functionalities. It makes sense to use it if you want to automate your regression test cases that you don't want to do manually every time a new fix has been received or a new feature has been deployed.

You should definitely try other options if you want to test the APIs without any testing on the UI level.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium type of testing can be done are:

1. Functional Testing
2. Regression Testing
3. Sanity Testing
4. Smoke Testing
5. Responsive Testing
6. Cross Browser Testing
7. UI testing (black box)
8. Integration Testing

You can automate : WAB, WAP, APP (Mobile App) applications using selenium.

**Yes**, Selenium can be used for UI testing. Selenium can be used to automate the manual interaction steps.

**Yes**, you can check textual information as well. As Selenium WebDriver object triggers real events in the browser: mouse clicks, button clicks, entering text, and events from the keyboard.